# Is spin-orbit coupling really necessary for topological insulators

Tags: topological-insulators

I have heard that for an insulator to be non-trivial, large spin-orbit coupling is necessary.

However, I have read the definition of $Z_2$ topological invariant and chern number. In no way can I recognize what role spin-orbit coupling plays in topological transition. The only relationship is that spin-orbit coupling can drive a band inversion, which I suppose some other factors may also lead to.

So, is spin-orbit coupling really necessary for topological insulators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a topological insulator means a symmetry-protected topological state with $U(1)$ and time reversal symmetries. I believe you are using the same definition, since you are talking about the $Z_2$ topological invariant. In this case, spin-orbit coupling is necessary in the sense that it is responsible for breaking the $SU(2)$ spin rotational symmetry. If the $SU(2)$ spin rotational symmetry is unbroken, the two spin components will have the same $Z_2$ topological invariant, so the total system has a trivial topological invariant and is not a topological insulator.

Answer (score 1):

I guess no. Su-Schrieffer-Heeger (SSH) chain  is one of the simplest topological insulators and has no spin-orbit coupling.